# How to collect reaction on messages (Microsoft Bot Framework)?

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I was following this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/25.message-reaction/bots/messageReactionBot.js) for collecting reactions to messages. Everything was working fine until I've started using Hero card.

When I send Hero card then response from `await context.sendActivity()` is empty object instead of resource identifier hence I am unable to attach reaction to that hero card later on.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

I am using Node.js SDK and Teams channel.

Comment: It looks like it is known issue https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues/1122 and the solution is to just send 2 messages separatly - first message will be text and second will be hero card with buttons.

Comment: Ouh I've stumbled upon another interesting thing. When you send only hero card as the attachment of the activity without setting anything else {attachments: [heroCard]} MS Teams will receive only one message and hence it will send you back resource identifier (instead of 2 when you also specify text field in activity). But unfortunately it seems like Hero Card does not support Markdown formatting which I need since I am using QnA Maker.

Comment: Markdown is currently supported only in Adaptive card .Could you please try using [Adaptive cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#formatting-cards-with-markdown)?